# Clean URLs not working in Drupal 8.1.8 and IIS 8

Tags: installation, uri

I am working on a new installation of Drupal 8 (8.1.8) on a Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8. I have installed PHP v7.0.9 and MySQL v5.7.14. During the installation process, I must have done something wrong. Upon completion, the home page is just the HTML without any styling and all of the links return an HTTP Error 404.

**The error**:
[image: The HTTP Error]

I've tried as much as I can think of (eg reinstalling IIS/Drupal/PHP/MySQL, triple checking passwords for MySQL, making sure URL Rewrite is working, etc)

**UPDATE:** I have also tried using drush to clear the cache.

**UPDATE #2:** It would seem as though my HTTP problem comes from the URL Rewrite module not working properly.

**UPDATE #3:** The site now has styling!!!!!! After reading [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/581558), I realized that there was no 'tmp' directory in '/sites/default/files'. However, there is still a problem with the URL Rewrite. I have to include '/index.php' in every url to go to any pages.

Comment: check for apache log error , presence of .htaccess file in root folder and SWITCH ON error reporting in settings.php

Comment: try to clean the cache, I had a similar issue yesterday and I solved cleaning the cache.

Comment: @AAjayKumarReddy I'm running IIS not Apache

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Are you talking about browser or Drupal cache? I cleared the browser with no success, but I cannot get to any of the admin pages because of the HTTP Error.

Comment: I'm talking about the drupal cache, you can install drush and use the command `drush cc all`

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Apparently I'm missing something with drush. I wasn't sure how to access it. I looked on the [Drush website](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/#windows) and decided to delete the whole thing and start over using Acquia Dev Desktop. When I did this and brought up drush, I was greeted by a whole slew of errors.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer ok, I got drush to work now, but I still have the same issue after the cache-rebuild command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the URL Rewrite module had become corrupted. After repairing it, I began receiving an HTTP Error 500.50. While in discussion with one of my colleagues, we learned that I needed to set HTTP_PROXY as a server variable. Then the whole thing worked!

Lots of stress off my shoulders.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1178209.aspx?URL+Rewrite+Module+Not+working+at+all

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/500-50-error-using-url-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a directory permission issue. Drupal is not able to write into web/sites/default/files. Give this file directory right permissions for your server user. (www-data in case of apache)

Comment: permissions seem to be correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure if Drush works on IIS but if it works the command for D8 is `drush cache-rebuild all`.

However, I share the answer of ssibal check the permissions, on sites/default/files and themes/your-default-theme

Comment: Drush apparently works if you use Acquia Dev Desktop. I've tried clearing the cache and checking permissions. Everything appears to be set correctly.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: I believe it is "bartik". This is a fresh install. I haven't been able to do anything else. As soon as the Drupal installer was finished, this is the result.

Comment: ok check out this path admin/reports/status on this path you can see the status of the website.

Comment: Still get the same HTTP Error

Comment: Check out this link http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-drupal-8-windows, but if you can change to LAMP much better.